# qubit/cbit arguments does not match gate expectation

Tags: qiskit

I am trying to use the code tutorials/finance/09_credit_risk_analysis.html for 3 assets. Face problem in running line 13: # define the registers for convenience and readability.
The error: ---> state_preparation.append(agg.to_gate(), qr_state[:] + qr_sum[:] + qr_carry[:])
CircuitError: 'The amount of qubit/clbit arguments does not match the gate expectation.' Please help me to debug.

Comment: Hello! I tried the cell 13 of [the tuto](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/finance/09_credit_risk_analysis.html) you are talking about and did not run into the error, did you change the code? Could you put more details of what you did/change exactly? It is a little difficult to help without more information

Comment: Yes, I have changed the code. I am using the code to use 3 assets instead of two. Accordingly, I have changed  the following:                                                                                 
# n_z = 2      # for 3 assets 6 qubits are required
n_z = 3
# n_z = 4
# z_max = 2
z_max = 3
# z_max = 4
z_values = np.linspace(-z_max, z_max, 2**n_z)
# p_zeros = [0.15, 0.25]
p_zeros = [0.15, 0.25, 0.6]
# rhos = [0.1, 0.05]
rhos = [0.1, 0.05, 0.25]
# lgd = [1, 2]
lgd = [1, 2, 3]
K = len(p_zeros)
alpha = 0.05